# Silverlight Accordion control not available in toolbox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

My configuration is:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- Silverlight tool 2.0 SDK & SP1
- Silverlight 2 toolkit March 2009

There are no Accordion control available in my Silverlight toolbox which I need for my project. I tried a lot to solve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Accordion` control requires you to include [`System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll`,  `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll` and `System.Windows.Controls.dll`](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20March%202009%20change%20list) if you're using it with Silverlight 2.

According to the [release notes](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/20430), it was new in the March 2009 toolkit release.

Comment: but on adding new item in silverlight component it shows an error "The following assembly are installed sdk assembly but could not be shown in customized toolbox bcoz they are missing one or more component plz make sure all necessary library are available". i have uninstalled & installed many times but no solution...

Comment: You must be missing a reference somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It must be on [Silverlight 2 Toolkit July](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/24246#DownloadId=73526).